# Can we lock a fixed postion map using map api

Tags: android, api, dictionary

I am working with a map api project. i want the map to only show a specific place map. be like our san andrias maps. i don't need the whole world map. any way for that?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out Static maps from Google Map. This may solve your requirement.

Details from Google site - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/